# ros node to follow walls to solve a maze.How to subscribe to LaserScan?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#!/usr/bin/env python

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from std_msgs.msg import Float32

class wall_follow():
    
    def __init__(self,r1=0.0,r2=0.0,threshold=5.0,i=0):
      self.r1=r1
      self.r2=r2
      self.threshold=threshold
      self.i=i
      rospy.init_node('wall_follow',anonymous=True) 
      rospy.loginfo("Press Ctrl+C to Exit")
      rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)
      self.cmd_vel = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel_mux/input/navi', Twist, queue_size=50)
      rate = rospy.Rate(.5)
      while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.loginfo("%g",self.i)
        self.i=self.i+1
        move_cmd=Twist()
        self.sub=rospy.Subscriber('scan',LaserScan,self.wall_info)
        ros.loginfo("range_1080 = %g range_720 = %g", self.r1,self.r2)
        if self.r2-self.r1 > self.threshold:
            move_cmd.angular.z=1.0
            move_cmd.linear.x=0.0
        elif self.r2-self.r1 < -1*self.threshold:
            move_cmd.angular.z=-1.0
            move_cmd.linear.x=0.0
        else:
            move_cmd.angular.z=0.0
            move_cmd.linear.x=0.3
        self.cmd_vel.publish(move_cmd)
        rate.sleep()    

    def wall_info(self,scan):
      self.r1=scan.ranges[1080]
      self.r2=scan.ranges[720]
      rospy.spin()

    def shutdown(self): 
      rospy.loginfo("Stopping TurtleBot")
      self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
      # Give TurtleBot time to stop
      rospy.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    wall_follow()
  except:
    rospy.loginfo("End of the trip for TurtleBot")
```

---

The is my Latest code for wall follower node.Logically the bot should move along its left wall(when placed near the left wall of maze entry point). But when I run this code on my turtlebot, I don't get any error, however it doesn't move.
This is all I see :

[INFO] [WallTime: 1477891660.282792] Press Ctrl+C to Exit
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477891660.298116] 0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477891660.320208] End of the trip for TurtleBot
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477891660.436050] Stopping TurtleBot

Clearly since the first index i=0 is getting printed, the scope is entering the while loop, but is not carrying on.
Since I am very new with ros I am not sure it this is a syntactical error, or perhaps a problem with the " self.sub=rospy.Subscriber('scan',LaserScan,self.wall_info) " statement,  or the wall_info(self,scan) function.

Please Help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246830/ros-node-to-follow-walls-to-solve-a-maze.how-to-subscribe-to-laserscan?/) by [Shubhayu Das](https://answers.ros.org/users/28390/shubhayu-das/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first message you see is `End of the trip for TurtleBot` , which indicates that your code is going into the `except` section at the last 5 lines of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    wall_follow()
  except:
    rospy.loginfo("End of the trip for TurtleBot")
```

Since this is getting into the `except` block, it means that there's some kind of exception being thrown in `wall_follow()`. I'd recommend that you either print the exception that's thrown, or remove the try/except block so that you can see where this exception is coming from.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shubhayu Das](https://answers.ros.org/users/28390/shubhayu-das/) on 2016-10-31**:
Thank you for the reply. I have updated the code. The problem there was that I wasn't running "rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node"
Sorry of the armature work. But i am still getting a error.
Pls Check out my next post / question